# private method `received_messages' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have create a messaging inbox from scratch. It has been working for over a week, and now it broke down giving me a "private method `received_messages'" error with the title "NoMethodError in MessagesController#index".

For some reason when I pushed a new update to Github yesterday using the app (I don't push using terminal) parts of my application stop working that I had to fix. I know for certain when you push files it doesn't change your code, however this isn't the first time it has happen. Anyone know how I can fix this error?

I only receive the error when I click submit on new message.

messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recepient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user_id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.readingmessage if @message.recepient == current_user
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user_id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

Comment: `received_messages` is now private in `User`

Comment: So delete the private method? That was there last week and it was working fine (which was before the last commit from yesterday)

Comment: Without being able to examine the code before and after your commit its hard to diagnose, but as apneadiving said, the method appears to be private to the user class. I'm assuming in your code you have a line that reads `private`, after which your `received_messages` method appears. Either move the method above the `private` line, or remove the `private` line altogether.

Comment: Please show your User class

Comment: Thanks. Silly me, I did add a new private to another file. Problem fixed! It's always something so simple. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

As apneadiving and Teeg explained, a private method was blocking received messages. I added a new private method to user model which was on top of the file. Moved it to the bottom and everything is working great again.

Make sure if you add a private method to place it below so that it does not block other functions. Thanks!